# How to allow requests ICMPv4 from my application C++? Windows 8.1+

Tags: c++, windows, firewall, rules

I have a application that execute a tracert in determined Host, but when execute, my firewall blocked ICMP requests. Disabling the firewall my application run normally with results Ok. I need solve this problem in my application C++, because multiples computers run this application, it is not viable disable the firewall one by one.

Comment: Pick a language, c & c++ aren't the same.  Also, please see how to ask in [help]

Comment: You can "traceroute" with ICMP and UDP, but both require constructing "raw" packets which can require special privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is allowed required privileges, it can control the Windows Firewall through its API, described in detail here:

[Windows Firewall with Advanced Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff956124.aspx)

However, if permissions are not there, you can't do this, as this is exactly what the firewall is designed to do - protect the computer (and its user) from undesirable applications.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to have to create an entry rule on the firewall